# How to get view data during unit testing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I would like to check the array given to a view in a controller function has certain key value pairs.  How do I do this using phpunit testing?

```
//my controller I am testing


public function getEdit ($user_id)
{
    $this->data['user'] = $user = \Models\User::find($user_id);

    $this->data['page_title'] = "Users | Edit";

    $this->data['clients'] = $user->account()->firstOrFail()->clients()->lists('name', 'id');

    $this->layout->with($this->data);

    $this->layout->content = \View::make('user/edit', $this->data);
}

//my test
public function testPostEdit (){

    $user = Models\User::find(parent::ACCOUNT_1_USER_1);

    $this->be($user);

    $response = $this->call('GET', 'user/edit/'.parent::ACCOUNT_1_USER_1);   

    //clients is an array.  I want to get this 
    //array and use $this->assetArrayContains() or something
    $this->assertViewHas('clients');

    $this->assertViewHas('content');

}
```

Comment: this is pure phpunit?

Comment: mostly phpunit assertions, however it's using the laravel framework.

Comment: `assertViewHas()` isn't a basic phpunit extension. I guess you are using some Selenium stuff?

Comment: that's a laravel function

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR;** Try `$data = $response->getOriginalContent()->getData();`

---

I found a better way to do it.  I wrote a function in the TestCase which returns the array I want from the view data.

```
protected function getResponseData($response, $key){

    $content = $response->getOriginalContent();

    $data = $content->getData();

    return $data[$key]->all();

}
```

So to get a value from the $data object I simply use `$user = $this->getResponseData($response, 'user');`

Comment: `$content[key]->all()` acted as `$user->all()` and returned all the users! My mind was blown that this was happening and i cannot explain it how this happens. I had to remove `->all()` to work for me in Laravel 5.3. Anyway that is clean code. Thanx

Comment: It does not work if you put variables to view like that `view()->share($params);`

Answer (score 9):

Inside a test case use:

$data = $this->response->getOriginalContent()->getData();

Example:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class HomeTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $data = $this->response->getOriginalContent()->getData();

        // do your tests on the data
    }
}
```

Example dumping data so you can see what in data(array) passed to view:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class HomeTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $data = $this->response->getOriginalContent()->getData();
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

Should get something back like what's in image:

[image]

Comment: It does not work if you put variables to view like that `view()->share($params);`

Answer (score 6):

I managed it by doing it in a messy way. I used `assertViewHas`:

```
$this->assertViewHas('clients', array('1' => 'Client 1', '6' => 'Client2'));
```

Answer (score 4):

So looking at how `assertViewHas` is implemented [HERE](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php) it looks like, what the method does, is access the view's data after this call:

```
$response = $this->client->getResponse()->original;
```

In your code, the line:

```
$response = $this->call('GET', 'user/edit/'.parent::ACCOUNT_1_USER_1);
```

essentially returns the same thing as the line above it, namely a [`\Illuminate\Http\Response`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/72964e278ae2e34c40ecc9c00614596ee960ed4c/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php) (which extends the symfony component [`\HttpFoundation\Response`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html))

So, inside the `assertViewHas` function it looks like laravel accesses the data using `$response->$key`, so I would try to access the `clients` and 'content' variables through the `$response` object.

If that doesn't work try searching around the `TestCase` file in the Laravel framework ... I'm sure the answer is in there somewhere. Also try to dump the `$response` object and see what it looks like, there should be some clues there.

The first thing I would try, though, is accessing your data through the `$response` object.

Comment: thanks for digging for me - I didn't think to do that.  I don't think its possibly really to access it.  I did a `var_dump` of `response` it outputs an object.  The object has a private property of `data` which is an array.  The data object contains `clients`, however of course data is protected, so I cannot access it.  I did look in the classes for returner functions.  There are none and I don't really want to edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can access data in  the response and it can be checked..

```
public function testSimpleLastProducts() {        

    $res = $this->call('GET', '/');

    $this->assertResponseOk();

    $this->assertViewHas('lastProducts');

    $lastProductOnView = $res->original['lastProducts'];

    $this->assertEquals(6, count($lastProductOnView));       

}
```

Comment: It does not work if you put variables to view like that `view()->share($params);`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$response->getSession()->get("errors")
```

And from there you can check the contents of the message box for whatever error you might want verify.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this in 2019, I got:
`$response->getData()->data[0]->...my properties`

Still looking for a simpler way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, but my case was a bit special, because I push my data to view via `view()->share($params);` and in such cases the solution: `$content = $response->getOriginalContent()->getData();` does not give the data out.

and I could not use `$response->assertViewHas(...)` because my data was objects (models) and I needed to verify object properties (keys and id-s).

So my solution was

```
$data = $response->original->gatherData();
$this->assertSame($currency->key, $data['currency']->key);
```

Tested on Laravel 8

Comment: You should avoid doing this as it is "uglier" than simply using [`assertViewHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-view-has), there is no problem if it is an object or not, as you can pass a second parameter it being a closure, so you just need to return `true` or `false`, so you do that check inside the closure. Check the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a3282a9674adebd432506ca196d3e27bf2473f57/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php#L848-L849) to see more. Other [example](https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/831206778914349056).

Comment: I know anyone reading my previous comment will say "source code is doing `$response->original->gatherData();` behind scenes, so why I should not do it?" just because that is a framework problem, not yours, you have to use what it is understandable, it is better to assert using `assertViewHas` that it is understandable by anyone, than using `->original->gatherData()` (as it could later change because Laravel wants to use other names or stuff), but the assertion method will not change.

Comment: @matiaslauriti. I agree, it is better to avoid using undocumented functions and properties. I also agree that it is a good idea to use closures, even though I personally consider them ugly and clunky. One thing is making me careless about using the provided solution is that - I use them in the unit tests. If Laravel "wants to use other names or stuff", my unit tests will show it  before the code goes to production. Thank you for your attention to my answer.