# How to get Response variables in a Laravel PHPUnit test?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I am testing a controller method and I am accessing a route in a test.

Then I would like to make sure that the correct model was returned in the view and was loaded with all of the correct relationships.

I know that I can do this:

```
$this->assertViewHas("content");
```

But can how can I verify that the content model that was returned into the view has the correct, for example, category? i.e. how can I get the content model object and then do something like

```
$this->assertEquals($content->category->name, "category 1");
```

?

Comment: Why not grab the actual controller method and test to make sure it has the right info?

Comment: Even if I do grab the actual controller, it returns a View. How do I access the Content model object from the view? I guess that would be a solution to my question, but I don't know the answer.

Comment: Checking the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php), it appears you can use something like `->assertViewHas($key, $value)`.

Comment: @CalebAnthony Yes I have seen that but maybe I am getting confused. I know I can do ```->assertViewHas('content', $value)``` but what I want to do is ```->assertViewHas('content->category', $value)``` and this returns null (I think because trying to access the View's 'content' attribute returns an Eloquent object and not a Model. I am not exactly sure. Or because the view doesn't have a 'content->category' attribute. But in any case, i haven't been able to get it to do what I want.

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.2.45

Comment: As long as you're not actually wrapping it in single quotes (which would tell PHP it's a string), it must mean that the value actually doesn't exist.

Comment: Well when I do ```->assertViewHas('content')``` it comes back true. When I dd the View object's 'content' key value doesn't contain the category relationship, in fact it is some eloquent object that I am not too familiar with. That's why I'm asking this question- because im not actually getting back the object I want to be getting back, and I want to know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get view data during unit testing in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139026/how-to-get-view-data-during-unit-testing-in-laravel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get your content from the response like this:

```php
$content = $response->getOriginalContent()->getData()['content'];
```

`getData()` returns the data sent to the view as an array.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`assertSee()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.html#method_assertSee):

```
$response->assertSee("category 1");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to get the array that's passed to the view:

```php
$response->original->getData()
```

This comes from *Illuminate/Http/ResponseTrait* ([link to docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/ResponseTrait.html)).

Comment: This is just a property shortcut to Vito Meuli's 2017 answer.

Comment: Yup I think it reads cleaner so wanted to share with the community

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$your_desired_data = $response->assertSee('var_tag');
```

and if it's an array of data you can access its data by:

```
$first_name = $your_desired_data['first_name'];
```