# Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertViewHas()

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i have this test for create function of controller

```
public function createTest()
{   
    $user = factory(App\User::class)->create([
        'email' => 'testuser@arabiaweather.com',
        'password' => bcrypt($this->password),
        'type' => 'admin'
    ]);
    $this->be($user);
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/client/1/profile/2/data');
    var_dump($response);

    $response->assertViewHas('client', 1); 
    $response->assertViewHas('clientProfile', 2);

    $this->visit('/client/1/profile/2/data/create')

    ->seePageIs('/client/1/profile/2/data/create');
     $this->user->delete();

}
```

I got this error

```
 Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertViewHas()
```

how i can solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't `$response->assertViewHas('client', 1);` be `$this->assertViewHas('client', 1);`? You are searching for undefined method in response!

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139026/how-to-get-view-data-during-unit-testing-in-laravel

Comment: but i got this 
The response was not a view.
Failed asserting that false is true.

Comment: `$this->assertViewHas` as @Thamilan sayed and like explained here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/using-assertviewhas-with-route-prefixing-with-laravel-5

Comment: i try this $this->assertViewHas