# Test Variables Passed To View In Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5

Is it possible to test the value of variables that are passed to a view when using the `TestCase` class for testing in Laravel?

I know we can test the content of the HTML, but there are instances where the contents of the variables passed to the view are more important than the view itself.

The variables are being passed from the controller to the view using

`return view('user_list', compact('user_list', 'timezone', 'roles', 'countingArray', 'billingDate'));`

Comment: **See also** stackoverflow.com/[How to get view data during unit testing in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139026/how-to-get-view-data-during-unit-testing-in-laravel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, see [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-view-has). There are both `assertViewHas` and `assertViewHasAll` which give you slightly different options. `assertViewHas` will allow you to also assert the value of said variable and `assertViewHasAll` will allow you to check that an array of variables are provided to the view.

```php
$response = $this->get(route('your.route'))

$response->assertViewHas($key, $value = null);
```

Comment: You can also pass a Clousure as the second parameter and do any check you want, it just has to return true or false for the assertion to pass or fail